# Android : Show dialog on onResume event

Tags: android

I have an alert dialog in my activity. When the user presses the home button when the dialog is dismissed, i would like to have it re-open when the activity resumes.

Right now, i am dismissing the alert `onPause()` event of the activity.
How can i do this?

Comment: Show some code, and elaboarte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show dialogs with DialogFragment, it handles state automatically.

Comment: @Chris you can find some examples here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

Answer (score 1):

probably you could have a variable that indicates that the alert dialog is showing.

```
bool isAlertShown=false;
```

set it to `true` when the dialog is `shown`.

set it to `false` when the dialog is `dismissed`.

`onResume` event of your activity, check if the variable is `true`, if yes, you should be showing the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show every time when your activity resumes show it in your activity's onResume()

if you want to show dialog in case dialog was showing before user pressed home declare a variable such as "isDialogShown" and set it true or false. Do not forget to save your flag variable onSavedInstanceState()

I advice to use Dialog Fragments (http://android-developers.blogspot.com.tr/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html) for these kind of operations.